# make listview show only the first line of each item

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

i want to make a listview items show only one line with ... in the end when the string of the item is more then one line
just like this

item 1 is very good.

i want to make it looks like this

item 1 ....

because the list view bounds will be at "is" 
So, I don't want to have only a one line
I have a basic action bar activity with list view layout and the XML code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Note that the items will be added dynamically.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add these two line on your textview of listview adapter item.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

`singleLine` is depricated so please use `maxLines` like

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: I have the standard list view and items will be added with ArrayAdapter in java with no custom adapter
is it possible to do this or i have to make a custom adapter

Comment: You need to make custom array adapter then you can modify it as per your expectation.

Comment: @AliHabbash if you wanna to be update for latest updates on android please subscribe my channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA5HRmlkT7bqbO56EIlT0UQ

Answer (score 0):

Sir use below code in textveiw

```
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:background="@color/black"
```